# Why align="center" not overriding on {text-align:right;}

Tags: css, xhtml

Why `<td align="center">5</td>` not overriding on `table.finTable tbody tr td {text-align:right;}`

Answer (score 5):

Inline CSS styles override CSS, but inline attributes are not always overrided.

Change your td to `style="text-align:center"` instead of `align="center"`

Answer (score 1):

CSS has precedence over old-style attributes.

At least it should be that way, so that older (now no more existent) browsers that does not understand CSS can render the content with old-style attributes, while newer browsers (all browsers nowadays) will render using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

CSS rules take higher precedence than element attributes. If you want to override it, use an inline style rule:

```
<td style="text-align: center;">5</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

inline style overrides style through css.
align="center" being inline has higher precedence and is not overridden.

btw, why would you give an element an inline style when you want it overridden through your style sheet?